# task_struct не выводит все процессы

Tags: linux, c

Доброго времени суток. Пишу модуль ядра, который выводит все процессы из ядра. Проблема в том, что выводит лишь часть процессов. Вот код:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h> 
#include <linux/module.h> 
#include <linux/sched.h> 
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
int init_module( void )  
{ 
 /* Выбираем отправную точку */ 
 struct task_struct *task = &init_task;

 /* Перебираем элементы списка задач, пока снова не встретим init_task */ 
 do {
      printk( KERN_INFO "Process: %s pid:[%d] \n", 
               task->comm, task->pid);

  } while ( (task = next_task(task)) != &init_task );

 return 0;

}

void cleanup_module( void ) 
{ 
  return; 
}
```

Comment: а [такой](http://stackoverflow.com/a/940481/4827341) код тоже не все процессы выводит? // кстати, а как именно вы определили, что «не все»?

Comment: А еще обратите внимание, что везде, где в ядре используется for_each_process перед циклом обязательно вызывается rcu_read_lock, а после цикла rcu_read_unlock. Без низ список процессов может 10 раз перестроится пока вы его читаете что приведет к непредсказуемым последствиям

Comment: @alexanderbarakin  должно выводить все запущенные процессы, но выдает лишь малую часть, при том что в системном мониторе показывает >100.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тот код, что вы указали, аналогичен моему.

Answer (score 1):

Поправил код. Чтобы вывести все процессы юзайте cat /var/log/Messages Скидываю код :

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/string.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
int init_module(void)
 {
   struct task_struct *task = &init_task;
    rcu_read_lock();
  /*
   перед циклом обязательно вызывается rcu_read_lock, 
   а после цикла rcu_read_unlock. Без низ список процессов
   может 10 раз перестроится пока вы его читаете что приведет 
   к непредсказуемым последствиям
  */
 do 
  {
    printk(KERN_INFO"%s [%d]\n",task->comm , task->pid);
     if (strncmp("chrome", task->comm,sizeof(task->comm)) == 0) {
       force_sig(SIGKILL,task);
       //sys_kill(task->pid,SIGKILL);
     }
   } while ((task = next_task(task))!= &init_task);

   rcu_read_unlock();
   return 0;
}

 void cleanup_module(void)
 {
  printk(KERN_INFO "Cleaning Up.\n");
 }
```